# Concatenating files from path names

Tags: bash, concatenation, cat

I have around 1000 text files, each of them containing a list of different paths of texts.for each file, i want to have a one text file, with all the texts inside those paths concatenated. 
For example a file looks like this:

```
path: data/www.saglikekibi.com/can/index.html?p=2637.html.txt name: index.html?p=2637.html.txt
path: data/www.bebek.com/blog/yazi/yasasin-anneyim-editorden/5259/saglikli-beslenen-organik-ipek/index.html?blogpageno=1.html.txt name: index.html?blogpageno=1.html.txt
path: data/www.bebek.com/blog/yazi/yasasin-anneyim-editorden/5259/saglikli-beslenen-organik-ipek/index.html.txt name: index.html.txt
path: data/www.bebek.com/blog/yazi/yasasin-anneyim-editorden/5259/saglikli-beslenen-organik-ipek/index.html?blogpageno=2.html.txt name: index.html?blogpageno=2.html.txt
```

How can i find and concatenate these into one file?

Comment: `cat file1 file2 file3 > newfile`

Comment: sometimes there are 1000 lines of paths in just one of the files, i want to concatenate all those paths.

Comment: What I put in will take all those files and stuff them into a single file. You should show what you expect for output, because I have no idea what you're talking about with "concatenate".

Comment: Do you want to open the path contained in the files ? Or concat anything in all files to a single one ? your *path* thing is confusing here

Comment: every path shows the path of a text file, and i want to use those texts, so not the path names

Comment: So for *path: data/www.saglikekibi.com/can/index.html?p=2637.html.txt name: index.html?p=2637.html.txt* you want the text inside *index.html* ? I guess all path lines have the same structure *path: ... name: ...* ?

Comment: yes exactly, data/www.saglikekibi.com/can/index.html?p=2637.html.txt this is a text for example, and i want all these in one file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try :

```
#!/bin/bash

FILES=/path/to/*
for f in $FILES
do
  cat $f | cut -d' ' -f2 | xargs cat >> all.txt
done
```

I assumed the path is always the 2nd column separed by a space

Comment: this is working thank you:) but how can i get this in a loop for every file in a folder?

Comment: __FILES=/path/to/*__ this list every file in the folder /path/to so you can change that part to your folder. Don't forget the __/*__ at the end

Comment: @oezlem could you validate the answer if the problem got solved ?

Comment: sorry I forgot, it works perfectly, + i finally understood how to do it, so thank you:)